# Set endorsed directory in Tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat, endorsed

I want to set the endorsed directory for Tomcat6 so it can use certain libraries instead of the default ones.

So, when I run this in a standalone application:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));
```

It prints:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/endorsed
```

However, when I do it an application running in Tomcat, it prints a blank line.

I have tried to modify `tomcat6.conf`, with this (and restarting, of course):

JAVA_OPTS="**-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed** -Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

But it still doesn't seem to know that property.

So, how can I tell Tomcat where the endorsed directory is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setting this option in tomcat6.conf:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed
```

is not enough. It is required to create a variable called JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS. So these two lines are needed in tomcat6.conf:

```
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS="/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed"
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS [-Djava....]"
```

Not really well documented issue, I think.

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 6 see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

On Ubuntu the startup script in /etc/init.d/tomcat8 will refer to a config in **/etc/default/tomcat8** which has JAVA_OPTS, you can add to it (it uses default env config to build up a complete JAVA_OPTS, so make sure you don't accidentally replace them).

Comment: Thx, but there is only generic information in that document about this issue.